# Using a separate thread to create the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I need to create an instance of a class, but the problem is that the `__init__` part of said class is somewhat time-consuming, and there's other stuff to do in the meantime. I'll use dummy classes for this example, creating an object with a 2048 bit prime, which is slow enough to really be noticeable:

```
from Crypto.Util import number

class Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # SNIP: Set up GUI and various other
        self.slowPoke = SlowPoke()

class SlowPoke():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.ready = False
        # SNIP: Set some self.basic stuff that takes practically no time at all from arg1
        self.largeprime = number.getPrime(2048)
        self.ready = True
```

I do not really need `self.slowPoke` right away, so is there a way I can have it created in a separate thread and just take its time, while the Gui and other stuff in the main thread can keep moving?

I tried to generate the prime with `concurrent.futures`

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(number.getPrime(2048))
    self.largeprime = future.result()
```

...but the delay still happens. Presumably because the Gui is waiting for `__init__` of SlowPoke to finish, and that's still running in the parent thread.

Comment: Please show what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: I think it is `submit(number.getPrime, 2048)` otherwise you're submitting the **result** of the function, not the function to execute and its arguments

Comment: @mguijarr Well, that cleared the error, and the prime is now generated... but the Gui still freezes while it's doing so, as `__init__` is running in the parent thread awaiting a response.

Comment: @Jarmund do not ask for the future result immediately - do something in between, like displaying the GUI, then check if the future is done and get the result...

Comment: @Wolf It's just an example of something time-consuming